# Blending GPUImageMovie with Particle Effects Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

How can I blend a `GPUImageMovie` with a particle effect animation?

Basically, I have a `SkView` which is having a `SKEmitterNode` to generate particle animation. When I attach this `SkView` to the parent view, I am able to see the particle animation. So, my particle animation is getting rendered on the screen.

However, I want to be able to do blend this particle animation with `GPUImageMovie` at the pixel buffer level.

One possible way is to capture the snapshot of the `SkView` for every frame and try to merge this frame with `GPUImageMovie`. However, I am not sure if this is a good way.